# How to combine Scatter chart and area spline chart ?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i'm new to **high-chart**.
i need to  combine Scatter chart and area spline chart.
anybody please help me out .

Comment: This will get you started http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-regression

Answer (score 3):

You can use two `series` with different types of chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/hJm2J/